# CSS added to PHP file doesn't show up at all?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to add a CSS file to my PHP file, but for some reason it's not working... Can someone help me out?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>Lab Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>


<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $incomeErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $income = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }
```

There's more code but I haven't added it.

Comment: check your console

Comment: check folder name and path was correct or not

Comment: wokring locally or server ? if on server provide link so we guys can check. if  you working on local machine. just check if your project has Folder with name CSS and having file name style.css inside it.

Comment: @RohitGautam Locally, using WAMP Server. Folder structure is linked correctly, there is a CSS folder with my file style.css inside of it.

Comment: Check console for errors also do an inspect element if the CSS is rendered

Comment: ok just view-source (ctrl+u) of your project and check if Css/style.css is loading or not. if it's loading just click on this to view enitre css code. if code exists then it should work. just hard Refresh your project.

Comment: Make sure your css folder in caps otherwise it will create issue online atleast or you can rename it to small like href="css/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/style.css" />` to align your css file with your php file?